# Adminhtml new custom Tab in the config section is not showing up

Tags: adminhtml, admin-panel

i'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and right now i am working on a new extension and i want to add new module with tab in the admin panel.

Here is what i've done so far:

/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </models>  
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in:
/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <vivas translate="label" module="vivasindustries_smsnotification">
            <label>Vivas Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </vivas>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <vivas translate="label" module="vivasindustries_smsnotification">
            <label>Extension Options</label>
            <tab>vivas</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

            <groups>
                <vivas_group translate="label" module="vivasindustries_smsnotification">
                    <label>My Extension Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                    <fields>
                        <vivas_input translate="label">
                            <label>My Input Field: </label>
                            <comment>My Comment</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </vivas_input>
                        <vivas_select translate="label">
                            <label>My Dropdown: </label>
                            <comment>Source model provider Magento's default Yes/No values</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        </vivas_select>
                    </fields>
                </vivas_group>
            </groups>
        </vivas>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Helper/Data.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract 
{

}
```

With this done i receive the following error when i open my admin panel:

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Vivasindustries_Smsnotification_Helper_Data' not found in /home/superweb/public_html/store/app/Mage.php on line 547

When i change the name of the FOLDER `SmsNotification` to `Smsnotification` this error is gone, but there is any new tab in the System->Configuration...

So guys can you help me out to create a new tab in the Admin panel ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your `<helpers>` node.

```
 <global>

 ...

     <helpers>
         <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
         </smsnotification>
     </helpers>

 ...

 </global>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lex,You need define the helper class of your module.You need define helper at  config.xml

```
 <helpers>
         <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
         </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
     </helpers>
```

under global tag